# How to write in a logarithmic plot a text in each decade in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, logarithm

I need to write a different number in each decade, in the bottom or top of my logarithmic plot.

I have these numbers in an array `N`. There is a way to automate the process without write a `for` loop for each decade?

In each decade there are 9 numbers, if I have two or three decades, how can write:

```
for i = 1:18
   text(x(i), y, num2str(N(i)));
end
```

where, `y` never change, `N(i)` are my numbers, and `x(i)` their position **that I'm looking for**.

[image: This is an example of my plots]
I would like put in the orange box (or in the top) the number of black dots.

Comment: What are the exact values of `x` and `y`?  Is `x` increasing by a power of 10 to respect the increase in decade?

Comment: Show us an example plot as well.

Comment: OK, I totally misunderstood your problem.  What Nitish has written below should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I might have misunderstood your question. One interpretation is of using `xticks` (explained below). The other is of placing text.

If all you wanted to do is place text at different locations, it's quite simple given that `text` also accepts vectors.

```
x = 0:1:5;
y = x;
plot(x,y);
text(x+0.25,0.5*ones(6,1),{'One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six'})
```

yields:

[image]

---

Unless you specifically want to position your labels, I would suggest that you use [xticks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).

For e.g.:

```
y = 0:1:5;
x = exp(-y.^2);
semilogx(x,y);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six'})
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: Never mind.  I seem to have misunderstood the OP's problem.  This is fine.

Comment: I've tried with `for i = 1:15, if i>9, k=(i-9)*10; else k=i; end, text(k,.015,num2str(N(i))),end` but this isn't the solution that I'm looking for.
Tomorrow I test your solution. Thank you.

Comment: But I like your solution. Thank you again.